# How to use css custom styles in cshtml page?

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

I created a custom css button class in my site.css file in an asp.netcore mvc web application. For some reason, this styling does not show up when I try to use it in a cshtml view. I've tried adding the link, and I've tried adding the style to the Layout page, neither of them work? What am I missing?

My site.css file has this custom button class.

```
.custom-button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

This is what my view looks like.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "PlaylistBuilder";
}
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </head>
      <center>
        <h2>PlaylistBuilder</h2>
        <input type="button" class="custom-button" value="Create Playlist with your top songs" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("TopSongCreator", "Playlist")'" />
        <input type="button" class="custom-button" value="Create Playlist with recently played songs" class="btn" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("RecentlyPlayed", "Playlist")'" />
      </center>
```

Tried the first comment, still doesn't work. This is what my view looks like now. Do I need to change something in the layout file?

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "PlaylistBuilder";
}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@(Url.Content("~/css/site.css"))" />
    <center>
        <p style="font-family:'Arial'; font-size:72px; font-weight:bold">
            Playlist Builder
        </p>

        <input type="button" value="Create Playlist with your top songs" class="custom-button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("TopSongCreator", "Playlist")'" />
        <input type="button" value="Create Playlist with recently played songs" class="custom-button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("RecentlyPlayed", "Playlist")'" />

    </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

That view is inserted into the middle of the body element somewhere. It would malform the HTML to place a head element there, and as such the link doesn't act like you are expecting it to.

In addition, the tilde (~) is relevant to razor's helper, and doesn't mean relative to the project's top scope in normal href attributes. You should still use the helper here.

Remove the `<head>` element definition and just use the link. Use the helper.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@(Url.Content("~/css/site.css"))" />
```

Comment: This still doesn't work. For some reason it doesn't employ my class even though it seems like it can access it.

Comment: The general convention is `~/Content/site.css` from asp.net mvc. Are you sure that the href path is correct?

Comment: @djangouser - Another thing to consider is that if the .css file has changed, but was previously loaded, you may be just using the cached version of css. Ensure that you get the updated version by using SHIFT+F5 to reload your view. It also may make sense to use what is called a "cache breaking mechanism" in order to ensure that your clients are forced to update their version when you push it out for release.